# Audio breakup on laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I keep getting audio issue on my laptop (Lenovo T460s Win 10). It's basically clicks and does this stuttering thing. Things I have tried:

Updating audio drivers
Buying a FiiO K1 DAC (presumably it does use the different drivers but it is class compliant)
Trying Bluetooth and regular speakers
Online and Offline audio files

The really weird thing thing is that when I have done major updates (i.e. BIOS) it will be fine for a few days.

Can't think what else to do to fix it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi I haven't fixed it fully but if anyone has any interest in such a niche problem this kind of helped. I downloaded the Realtek HD drivers direct from the site and installed them (they uninstall the Lenovo ones) but this worked. Sort of. When I rebooted the machine the drivers were totally removed, perhaps a security feature of the laptop, I've not figured that out yet. But the mini FiiO DAC now works OK. So far! I'll ask Lenovo about the using the Realtek drivers but I think it's something they couldn't support. Cheers. Sorry to repeat the comment above. If anyone can help me remove my comment that would great.

Comment: Win 10 has some nasty compatibility issues using anything other than 44.1kHz. I'd try switching to that [CD rather than DVD, if it's not labelled in kHz]